# browser submits utf-8 with form post even though page encoding set to iso-8859-1 - with jsf 2.1/tomcat 7

Tags: jsf-2, unicode, utf-8, tomcat7, iso-8859-1

I have my JSF Template/pages encoded as follows:

```
<h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

And similarly, form submit defined as:

```
<h:form id="mainForm" autocomplete="off" acceptcharset="ISO-8859-1">
```

I am using the OmniFaces CharacterEncodingServlet, with it defined in my web.xml as follows:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
             <description>The character encoding which is to be used to parse the HTTP request body. Defaults to UTF-8.</description>
             <param-name>encoding</param-name>
             <param-value>ISO-8859-1</param-value>
         </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
```

Yet:  When I submit a page input variable and POST to the server a value such as:  N日na, the string is NOT encoded during processing.  And I have no idea why this String is not being encoded?

I'm using JSF 2.1 and I thought that the above modifications would be sufficient to get a String that is encoded if any characters OTHER than ISO-8859-1 are entered.  That way, I can reject any foreign characters because our business logic and/or consuming applications do not support foreign characters.

Note that I am running the application within Eclipse/Tomcat 7 (not sure if this contributes to the issue).

Any suggestions/pointers are most appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried logging the actual raw http traffic between browser and server?

Comment: Sorry, before posting an answer, I'd like to know why you would fall back to a prehistoric character encoding which supports only a handful of Latin characters and not all those million other characters the world is aware of? (Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Hebrew, Cyrillic, etc) What exactly is the problem you're having with UTF-8 that is apparently forcing you to make it yet worse?

Comment: Hi BalusC - thanks for your reply.  I totally agree with you - but this is the requirement for the system.  Because we have other clients who are requesting this data through various other (legacy) implementations, we have to ensure the data is in only ISO-8859-1 format.  Currently we are unable to support UTF-8.  And sadly even though i have made the effort to set the page/accept encodings to 8859-1, the text is not encoded.  it comes through as UTF-8 chars.

Comment: Hi Karol S - thanks for your reply.  No, i have not tried that.  I can put in a filter that will log all incoming request post params.  Not sure if that would help.  Other than that, I'd have to dig a little to find the appropriate tool that would log the traffic incoming.  Any suggestions are welcome. I'm on Mac OSX and the servers run on my local as well as Linux machines